# React-native: How to use (and translate) typescript .tsx files with jsx in React-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx, tsx

I am new to React-native coming from reactjs+typescript. I am trying to set up a fairly simple project test and see how this technology works. I am using VS Code.

Following the basic tutorial, I have set up my project and I can run it in an Visual Studio Android Emulator.

Now I want to see how to create a custom .tsx file (say profile.tsx), write a **render function** and display it on the index page (index.android.js).

So I create a .tsx file:(I have omitted the various import statements at the beginning of the file)

```
export class Profile extend React.Component {

       render(){
           return <View> this is the profile view </View>
       }
}
```

Using VS Code I can compile this file and produce its corresponding profile.js and profile.js.map files.

The content of the profile.js is:

```
"use strict";
const react_1 = require('react');
const react_native_1 = require('react-native');

...

class Profile extent react_1.Component {

     render(){
          return react_1.default.createElement(react_native_1.View, null, "this is the profile view");
     }
}
```

At run time the line react_1.**default.createElement** blows up with this message:

**undefine is not an object (evaluating react_1.default.createElement)**

There is this "default" property, I don't what it is.

So how can I create a .tsx file containing some jsx code and properly transpile it in order to be properly consumed in a react-native application?

- P.S: This is my tsconfig.json file, I have enabled jsx with **jsx="react"**

Any help, suggestion, direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You have typos in `extend` and `extent`. Is this intentional or should it be `extends`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now TSC is transpiling ES6 modules syntax and later JavaScript engine is expecting the default export (similar to module.exports), which is not present. You should configure your TSC with `ES6` target and modules.

Try updating the compiler options in your `tsconfig.json` file as follow:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

With `ES6` target (modules defaults to `ES6` with it), your Profile class should be transpiled to:

```
class Profile extends Component {

     render(){
          return React.createElement(View, null, "this is the profile view");
     }
}
```

Also remember to install `react` and `react-native` type definitions, either using yarn (prefered with latest react-native) or npm: `yarn add @types/react-native @types/react -D` or `npm i @types/react-native @types/react -D`

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked! I am marking this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by avoiding to import the components and use * e.g. "import * as React from "react";"

This issue can be from JS compiling with tsc as well.